# How to iterate for each cell in Google Sheet range with hyperlinks and send batch photos to Telegram?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, bots, telegram

For example, I have this range with 10 Drive hyperlinks to images:

[image: F1:O1]

This script already sends **only one** photo (F1) to a group via Telegram Bot, but I need to iterate for each cell in this range to send every uploaded images (via Google Forms, max. 10), but it could be only one or ten pictures, so I need to stop the iteration if is an empty cell like N1 and O1.

```
photo_url = "DRIVE_URL";
id = "GROUP_ID";

sendPhoto(id,photo_url)

function sendPhoto(id,photo_url) {
var API_TOKEN = "BOT_TOKEN";

var payload = {
      'method': 'sendPhoto',
      'chat_id': String(id),
      'photo': photo_url,
      'caption': "Foto 1"
    }

    var data = {
      "method": "post",
      "payload": payload,
      'muteHttpExceptions':true,
    }
//var response = 
UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + API_TOKEN + '/', data);
//Logger.log(response);
}
```

*Plus, is it the same process to change the **name or caption** of every image? making this code dynamic:

```
'caption': "Foto 1"
'caption': "Foto 2"
'caption': "Foto 3" //...etc., until max. 10, sometimes is empty.
```

*Edited, this is the working code only to find data (URL photos in a Drive) inside a range of 10 cells (F2:O2):

```
function loopImage() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sh = ss.getSheetByName("AWESOME");
var vals =
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("AWESOME")
.getRange(2 +":"+ 2)
.getValues()[0],
lastColNum = vals.length
;
while(!vals.pop())
{ --lastColNum; }  
var range = sh.getRange(2, 6, 2, lastColNum-5); //The command will automatically adjust the range based on the last column of the F2:O2 range.

var data = range.getValues();
var photoArr = [];
for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){
photoArr.push({"type": "photo", "media": data[0][i], "caption": "Foto "+(i+1)})
}
if(photoArr.length > 0){
sendPhoto(JSON.stringify(photoArr));
}
}
function sendPhoto(photoArray) {
id = "GROUP_TOKEN";
var API_TOKEN = "BOT_API";
var payload = {
'method': 'sendMediaGroup',
'chat_id': String(id),
'media': photoArray,
}
var data = {
"method": "post",
"payload": payload,
"muteHttpExceptions":true,
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + API_TOKEN + '/', data);
Logger.log(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script below will loop through the first row of Sheet starting from column **F** up to the last column with data, creates an array of object of [InputMediaPhoto](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediaphoto), and send the array to **sendPhotoArray** function to send it to a Telegram group chat.

**Code:**

```
function loopImage() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName("Enter Sheet Name Here");
  var range = sh.getRange(1, 6, 1, sh.getLastColumn()-5); //The command will automatically adjust the range based on the last column of the first row.
  var data = range.getValues();
  var photoArr = [];
  for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){
    photoArr.push({"type": "photo", "media": data[0][i], "caption": "Foto "+(i+1)})
  }
  if(photoArr.length > 0){
     sendPhoto(JSON.stringify(photoArr));
  }
}

function sendPhoto(photoArray) {
  id = "Insert Chat ID here";
  var API_TOKEN = "Insert API TOKEN HERE";
  var payload = {
        'method': 'sendMediaGroup',
        'chat_id': String(id),
        'media': photoArray,
      }

      var data = {
        "method": "post",
        "payload": payload,
        'muteHttpExceptions':true,
      }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + API_TOKEN + '/', data);
}
```

**Sample Data:**

[image]

**Output in Telegram:**

[image]

**File Caption:**

[image]

### References:

- [Telegram sendMediaGroup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)

Comment: I am still having one picture in the Telegram group, this could be because of the URL format (https://drive.google.com/uc?id=ID)? or the caption name? it didn't seem to get in a loop iteration work

Comment: @CarlosHernándezQuiñones - I updated my code above to make sure that the sheet the script referencing is correct.

Comment: @CarlosHernándezQuiñones - Could you share a sample spreadsheet? The Iteration should work. I used the same format of data from your example above. I also tried using `drive.google.com/uc?id=ID` `docs.google.com/uc?id=ID` and both are working. Caption is also not an issue since we iterate it in for loop.

Comment: I think the problem was that the last column data, maybe it was taking another column because I have another data in that sheet, I find how to get the last column only in the row 2 (maybe it was not the best way but worked) and now the album of max. 10 photos are being sent, I updated my post with that code.