# Send several documents in one message using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, telegram-bot

Well, I don't understand what am I doing wrong.

I can send one document, but nothing works when I try do modify the code to use several docs.

```
function test() {
  var doc = 'https://drive.google.com/file/d/**fileid**/view?usp=sharing';
  var docs = [
'https://drive.google.com/file/d/**fileid**/view?usp=sharing',
    'https://drive.google.com/file/d/**fileid**/view?usp=sharing'
  ];
  var blob = DriveApp.getFileById('**fileid**').getAs("application/pdf");
  var blob2 = [[
    {type: 'document', media: DriveApp.getFileById('**fileid**').getAs("application/pdf")},
    {type: 'document', media: DriveApp.getFileById('**fileid**').getAs("application/pdf")}
  ]];
  tgSendDoc(myid, 'test', blob);
}

function tgSendDoc(chatId, text, media) {
  var data = {
    method: "post",
    payload: {
      method: "sendMediaGroup",
      media: media,
      chat_id: String(chatId),
      text: text,
      parse_mode: 'HTML'
    }

  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot' + botToken + '/', data);

}
```

I might assume that there is a problem wit access to the file - but I've managed to send it as one document. So the problem is somewhere where I can't see it.

I even found similar question [regarding the photos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68836584/how-to-iterate-for-each-cell-in-google-sheet-range-with-hyperlinks-and-send-batc).

But simply changing links to PDF links from drive and typing "document" in type instead of "photo" also doesn't work.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Hi. "I even found similar question". It is VERY similar - did you notice how they had a method (a loop) to work through each of the photos? You need an equivalent in your script? You've got an array of URLs, but how does `blob2` distinguish between the `fileid` values in the `docs` array?

Comment: @Tedinoz well, on that variables before, just my recent attempts. even if I just put links to PDF, and change type to document 'photoArr.push({"type": "document", "media": data[0][i]})' - error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have found a solution. Reason why it all didn't worked because the wrong MIME type. While sending one document from Drive you can use direct link, to send several you need to put a link in a format of download the file.
like that:

```
var linkstart= 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=' + file_id

          var blob = values.map(function (row) { // values is a values from a range with files IDs
        var url = row[0];
        return {
          type: "document",
          media: linkstart + fileid,
          caption: ''
        };
      });
```